# How could i increase a every next object part exponentially with a value a attach?

Tags: python, python-2.7, 3d, polygon, maya

How could i increase every next object part exponentially more. example 1.part adding 1,5 ; 2.part 3 ;3.part 4,5 ,4.part 5; 5.part 6.5; 6.part 7; 7.part 8,5 and so on and so on 
the goal is to define a stair

Comment: What is an "object part"? A face, some attribute? Your question needs to be edited as it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: yes it´s a face so i can extrude every next face, i know i´m a total beginner ,but everyone starts like this.

Comment: Could you give us some example code? The usual starting point here is to start with something concrete and either ask why it does not work or how it can be improved

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of iterating over selected components. It works be selecting the faces you want to extrude and the executing the script.

Note: for the component selection order to work, you need to enable ***Settings/Preferences > Selection > Track selection order***.

I've added a bit of offset to the polyExtrudeFacet command, just to clarify that the faces are **not** kept together. You would have to change the script, if that's what you want. I'll leave that task to you.

Breakdown:

1. Get a list of the ordered selection.
2. Iterate over each array group.
3. Increment index and calculate local z translation value
4. Extrude the face in the local z axis.

[image: Script demo]

```py
import pymel.core as pm

def step_extrude():
    step_size = 1.5
    i = 0

    for faceArray in pm.ls(os=True):
        for face in faceArray:
            i += 1
            z = step_size * i
            pm.polyExtrudeFacet(face, 
                                constructionHistory=True, 
                                localTranslate=[0.0, 0.0, z], 
                                offset=0.2)

step_extrude()
```